# how can i make pull_to_refresh refresh when change city in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using the `pull_to_refresh package` to get a list of data from API

```
MedicalListModel result = await medicalListViewModel.fetchMedicalListPerCity(cityID: cityId, pageNumber: providerPageNumber.getPageNumber);
```

how can I make `pull_to_refresh package` refresh when choosing another city and get a list of data from API. "each city has a different data"

Comment: It's not clear why you want to trigger that package. You can either use `setState()` to rebuild the view with the added data from the selected city. Or you can Navigate back to this view. Is there a specific reason you want to trigger that package instead?

Comment: Just call the function you use in the pull_to_refresh package